# Select and subselect UPDATE Mysql case disciplines x techniques

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update, inner-join

I have the following case: I have the table "disciplines_units_technicians" with the following columns:

- discipline_id;
- unit_id;
- technical _id;

Initially there were two units and a third unit was added, which resulted in problems in the "UNITS X TECHNICAL" link

I NEED HELP TO MAKE THE FOLLOWING UPDATES:

First I select the table:

SELECT discipline_id FROM disciplines_units_technicians WHERE ?

I would like to SELECT the returns (repeated lines for 1, 2 and 3) with unit_id = 1, 2 and 3 and from this return make UPDATE in the discipline_id register where:

UPDATE disciplines_units_technicians SET unit_id = '0' where unit_id = '2'

AND WHERE:

UPDATE disciplines_units_technicians SET unit_id = '2' where unit_id = '3'

ONLY OF the "discipline_id" ids where they have 3 records in the table, that is, they include unit = 1, 2 and 3, but I don't know how to make a select and a subselect for update in this case, do not CONTEMPLATE discipline_id returns with repetition only for unit = 1 and 2, only if there is a unit = 3 in the return of the discipline_id.

Colum
[image]

[image]

Examples, just select returns that have units 1, 2 and 3 and make pos updates necessary

Comment: I'm having trouble following your description. Please add sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Revising your question: So if a single discipline_id has 3 units you want to update the unit_id 2 to 0 and 3 to 2 is that what you want? for all discipline_id's in the table. is that correct?

Comment: I added an example in the description, thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you  ask for:

```
update disciplines_units_technicians dut
inner join (
    select discipline_id
    from disciplines_units_technicians
    where unit_id in (1, 2, 3)
    group by discipline_id
    having count(*) = 3
) dut1 on dut1.discipline_id = dut.discipline_id
set dut.unit_id = case when dut.unit_id = 2 then 0 else 2 end
where dut.unit_id in (2, 3)
```

Basically this filters the table for `discipline_id`s that have all 3 `unit_id`s (1, 2 and 3), and updates `unit_id` 2 to 0, and 3 to 2.

Comment: Thanks, this logical solution really, run and work as expected as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Test with this script first and see if the output is what you want.

```
SELECT [discipline_id]
      , CASE WHEN [unit_id] = 2 THEN 0
             WHEN [unit_id] = 3 THEN 2
       ELSE [unit_id] END AS [unit_id]
      ,[technical_id]
FROM (
SELECT [discipline_id]
      ,[unit_id]
      ,[technical_id]   
      ,COUNT([discipline_id]) OVER(PARTITION BY [discipline_id]) AS [counter]
  FROM [Test].[dbo].[disciplines_units_technicians]
  GROUP BY [discipline_id]
          ,[unit_id]
          ,[technical_id]) A
          WHERE [counter] > 2
```